# Current.Session works strange

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a doubt about `HttpContext.Current.Session["someSession"]`.

In my website I have a empty grid which users can add some rows in the edit mode of the grid. When the user inserts a new row, I store it in a Session, so I have this class:

```
public static class DocumentSessionRepository
{
    public static IList<DocumentModel> AllDocuments()
    {
        return (IList<DocumentModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Documents"];
    }

    public static void Insert(DocumentModel product)
    {
        AllDocuments().Add(product);
    }

    public static void Delete(Guid? idDocument)
    {
        var target = GetOneDocument(p => p.IDDocument == idDocument);
        AllDocuments().Remove(target);
    }

    public static DocumentModel GetOneDocument(Func<DocumentModel, bool> id)
    {
        var one = AllDocuments().Where(id).FirstOrDefault();
        return one;
    }
}
```

The problem is that all the users are getting the same session, so if some user insert a new row in this session, other user can see it as well.

I think that I make some messy using this static class to manage this session variables. Or I'm missing something here.

Anyone can help me with this?

EDIT:

Places where i set and use the Session:

```
 public ActionResult InsertDocument(DocumentModel model)
 {
     //Some Code
     DocumentSessionRepository.Insert(model);
 }
```

View where i bind a grid with this Session.

```
  @(Html.Telerik()
      .Grid<DocumentModel>()
      .BindTo((List<DocumentModel>)DocumentSessionRepository.AllDocuments())
```

Comment: where do you set `HttpContext.Current.Session["Documents"]`?

Comment: @Igor see my edit on the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose problem is in  the `IList<DocumentModel>` instance. If this instance is shared for all users, it doesn't matter that session is user specific. Looks like all sessions share the same instance. Check class instantiation, for example if the class is instantiated in static field and than this field is stored in the session, all users will share this instance.

I'm 100% sure `Current.Session` works fine.